# Regex match number between 1 and 31 with or without leading 0

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I want to setup some validation on an `<input>` to prevent the user from entering wrong characters. For this I am using `ng-pattern`. It currently disables the user from entering wrong characters, but I also noticed this is not the expected behavior so I am also planning on creating a directive.

---

**I am using**

AngularJS: *1.6.1*

---

**What should the regex match**

Below are the requirements for the regex string:

- Number 0x to xx (example 01 to 93)
- Number x to xx  (example 9 to 60)
- Characters are not allowed
- Special characters are not allowed

Notice: 
the 'x' is variable and could be any number between 0 and 100.

*The number on the place of 'x' is variable so if it is possible to create a string that is easily changeable that would be appreciated!*

---

**What I tried**

A few regex strings I tried where:

1) `^0*([0-9]\d{1,2})$`

```
--> Does match 01 but not 1
--> Does match 32 where it shouldn't
```

2) `^[1-9][0-9]?$|^31$`

```
--> Does match 1 but not 01
--> Does match 32 where it shouldn't
```

---

For testing I am using https://regex101.com/tests.

**What am I missing in my attempts?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your aim is to match 0 to 100, here's a way, based on the previous solution.

```
\b(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)\b
```

Basically, there's 3 parts to that match...

`0?[1-9]` Addresses numbers 1 to 9, by mentionning that 0 migh be present

`[1-9][0-9]` covers number 10 to 99, the [1-9] representing the tens

`100` covers for 100

[Here's an example of it](https://regex101.com/r/Mlrh8z/1)

Where you to require to set the higher boundary to 42, the middle part of the expression would become `[1-3][0-9]` (covering 10 to 39) and the last part would become `4[0-2]` (covering 40 to 42) like so:

```
\b(0?[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-2])\b
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

https://regex101.com/r/BYSDwz/1

Comment: Thanks! But since the 'from' and 'to' are variable, say I want to go to max 32 how should the string then change? '^0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[02]$' wouldn't work. Also the string '02Test' also matches where it shouldn't.

Comment: To accept 32, 33 etc, change the last `[01]` to a range: `[0-2]`, `[0-3]` etc

Comment: thanks for the update. Now it also matches 32, 33 and so on. But there is still a problem. I updated the requirements for the regex. Is your solution is applicable?

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy: that's a completely different question. Yes, it's theoretically possible to create a regex to match a numeric range, but that makes little sense - numeric validations are simpler and less error-prone. Consider `ng-min`, `ng-max` and friends.

Comment: I don't understand the edits you've made or what 0x-xx and x-xx  mean.

Comment: @sweaver2112 added clarification